# HttpClient.SendAsync call results in multiple triggers on service side, returns internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, azure-api-apps

I have an ASP.NET Web API deployed on Azure App service. 
I am experiencing following error: For one specific business object my Web API's GET method is returning `Internal server error`, while for other business objects the same GET method is working fine.

When I debugged my Web API it turned out, that valid business object is returned, but… GET method was triggered multiple times (and on client side I see that it is called only once)

This is an excerpt where Web API is called from client code

```
// Create HTTP transport objects
HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
httpRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

// Set Credentials
if (this.Credentials != null)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await this.Credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await this.HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Besides - if I try to open **that same url** from browser (e.g.: https://myservice.com/api/businessObject/xxx) - request is performed only once (as it should) and correct results (Json) is displayed in browser.

Any suggestions what to try to figure why call from client side (for specific object) results in multiple Web API service executions and how to fix this?

My Web API service is deriving from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`

I got some information from exception, but it doesn't seem to be very helpful

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException' in Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll The thread 0x27fc has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

**EDIT**

I got some information from Azure Log stream, but that information does not seam to make sense… because this problem happens for one specific business object (and only when requested from my application - not failing from web browser), other business objects are working fine so I don't see how this could be related to access / web.config file...

*IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.*
..
*Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web servers machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code*

Comment: If you make the request from the browser without any stored cookies, like an incognito window, does the network trace show multiple requests?

Comment: @Crowcoder no, it shows single request and returns correct response. But I managed to get some information from Azure Log stream - I'll update my question with that